# check if exist inside two column

Tags: php, mysql, exists

need a help with a PHP/MySQL issue. I have a table named bids and two column named buyer and tagged both using int.

```
buyer
--------------
8
5
2

tagged
--------------
5
4
1
```

I'm trying to detect multiple same entry number. I want if a same number appears on both of the column it shouldnt display on the menu list anymore, hope yo understand.

Any tip?

code below

$query = "SELECT b.auction, b.buyer, b.bid, b.bidwhen, b.quantity, b.willwin, b.tagged, b.balance, u.nick, u.rate_sum FROM " . $DBPrefix . "bids b

LEFT JOIN " . $DBPrefix . "users u ON (u.id = b.bidder) WHERE b.auction = :auc_id

ORDER BY b.bid asc, b.quantity DESC, b.willwin asc"; $params = array(); $params[] = array(':auc_id', $id, 'int');

Comment: You should include the language as the tags so people who follow those are more likely to answer your question.

Comment: count(id) both table

Comment: how do i go about this heres the code am using 




// get tag name
$query = "SELECT b.auction, b.buyer, b.bid, b.bidwhen, b.quantity, b.willwin, b.tagged, b.balance, u.nick, u.rate_sum FROM " . $DBPrefix . "bids b




LEFT JOIN " . $DBPrefix . "users u ON (u.id = b.bidder)




WHERE b.auction = :auc_id ORDER BY b.bid asc, b.quantity DESC, b.willwin asc";




$params = array();




$params[] = array(':auc_id', $id, 'int');

Comment: What about `SELECT * FROM buyer WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tagged)` ?

Comment: how do i integrate that with the code i just droppped?